# Single supply 5V low noise hydrophone preamplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, electret

The title speaks for itself, I want to know if there is some circuit that provides low-noise, single supply operating at 5V and high gain to be used as a hydrophone preamplifier. The output of the hydrophone is equivalent to the output of an electret microphone.

I have found some great circuits like INA127, but none of them operate at 5V.

Do you know of any examples?

Comment: No, the title doesn't give us everything. What exactly do you mean by "high gain"? What is your definition of "low-noise"? What is the frequency range of interest? Do you have any constraints on power consumption or physical size?

Comment: Maybe INA155, if biased properly. The noise does not seem particularly low to me, and it has a fairly high corner frequency.

Comment: Is true, from my point of view all is clear but I need to be more precise. High gain, at least 20dB of gain. Low-noise, the lowest noise possible, I really don't have any certain value in mind. I don't have any constraints on power/size.

Comment: 20dB isn't "high gain" in most contexts.  This is exactly why hand waving like that doesn't belong in engineering.

Comment: The INA127 does operate at +/- 4V5 - why not just add a circuit to generate the negative rail voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use an op-amp for this and at low voltage supplies and with pretty decent low-frequency noise and low dc drift, the ADA4528 springs to mind: -

[image]

It's also rail-to-rail on both inputs and outputs. I've traded high frequency performance for ultra low noise and the low frequency end of the spectrum but without a definitive statement on either there is guesswork involved. Having said that I'm satisfied the B&K hydrophones are band limited to just above 100kHz: -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

[image]

You will have to look around to find a opamp that can run from a single 5 V supply and has suitably low noise.  We can't tell if this meets your noise spec, because "low" is no spec at all.

This will have a voltage gain of -10, which gives you the 20 dB you are asking for.  It also looks like a 2.5 V source with 3.3 kΩ in series, which might be good for driving your hydrophone directly.  You say it is electrically like a electret. Many electrets would be fine with this, but without a datasheet we can't tell, of course.

The output will be centered around 2.5 V.  That is probably just what you want if it will be fed into the A/D input of a microcontroller running from 5V.  If not, you may need to add a series capacitor to block the DC from the opamp so that whatever is downstream can set its own DC bias.

If you can't find a suitably low noise opamp that can run from a single 5 V supply, you can use that supply to make a wider ± supply to run the opamp from.

Comment: I am looking for the best circuit I could use in terms of supply voltage, amplification and also low-noise. I can't say I want a circuit performing 10nV/ sqrt (Hz), just I would like to know which are the best possibilities on the market. In the Hydrophone's datasheet there is not information about how has to be his biasing only that 'plug-in-power' should be provided.